# Can not access the camp select custom

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m intending to access a sub camp of electoral type, which is idioms> idioms and here elige between a list of idioms, between them ‘English’. But when the English bus searcher did not send me any dates

```
<?php
/*

EL PROBLEMA ES QUE NO ES UN VALOR DE TEXTO SINO UN SELECT Y SE GUARDA
EN LA BASE DE DATOS  COMO MATRIZ SERIALIZADA, SE DEBE MODIFICAL LA META CONSULTA

*/

require_once("../wp-load.php");
switch_to_blog(5);
echo '
    <form class="form form--search" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="custom_field" value="field_57c7fadfc5635" />
                <input type="search" name="s" class="search__input" placeholder="Buscar por organización" />
                <button type="submit" class="button button--submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
';
//AJAX
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'profesiones' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_key'               => 'nombre_profesion',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     =>  $_POST['custom_field'],
                    'value'   =>  $_POST['s'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre de la profesion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_field('plural').'</a></td>
            </tr>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

I can't access I don't know if "field_57c7fadfc5635" is wrong, that is, in the right place, I've seen examples that are like this, so I guess this is not the error

Now then the problem may be that it is not a text but an eligible field and does not behave like text